# Create a link by comparing two values

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I try to break down the problem into the simplest example possible, hope you can understand.
So the XML looks like this:

```
<!-- FruitsID12345 is the id I want -->
<Fruits id="system://data/Fruits/FruitsID12345/?language=en-GB" majorVersion="1">
    <Header> A header - not important </Header>
    <!-- interesting is 'Strawberry' and the 'id' behind it -->
    <Strawberry id="system://data/Strawberry/StrawberryID12345/?language=en-GB" version="2">
        <Description> Some text - not important </Description>
        <Content> Can be filled with content </Content>
    <Strawberry>
</Fruits>

<!-- There can be more Stawberries just with other IDs -->
<MuchMoreFruits>.....</MuchMoreFruits>

<Lemon>
    <!-- 'targetid' and 'href' are the same -->
    <Text> Click the following link:
        <Link targetid="system://data/Strawberry/StrawberryID12345/" 
              version="2" href="system://data/Strawberry/StrawberryID12345/">Click me 
        </Link>
    </Text>
</Lemon>
```

What I need:

```
{id from Fruits} {major-version from Fruits} {object-type from Fruits} {component-information}
```

component-information is the following:

```
{id from Strawberry} {version from Strawberry} {object-type from Strawberry}
```

So the solution should look like this:

```
<a href="" my.id="FruitsID12345" my.majorVersion="1" my.type="Fruits" 
   my.component="StrawberryID12345_2_Strawberry">Click me</a>
```

I have done the component-part so far which looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Link">
    <a>
        <!-- think I can put that part in <a> -->
        <xsl:attribute name="href"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="my.component>
            <!-- template to get the id -->
            <!-- substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(., 'data/'), '/'), '/') -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@targetid"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@version"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <!-- template to get the object-type -->
            <!-- substring-before(substring-after(@targetid, 'data/'), '/') -->
            <xsl:call-template name="objecttype"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
```

### So what is missing?

The information from <Fruits>.  Somehow I need to compare 'StrawberryID' in <Link> to StrawberryID which is inside <Fruits>.

Comment: So what exactly is the format you expect for the `Strawberry id="system://data/Strawberry/StrawberryID12345/?language=en-GB"`? Will there always be that suffix with `?language` for instance and it would work to compare e.g. `substring-before(@id, '?language')`? In general cross-references are best solved with `xsl:key` and use of the `key` function, doing it of part of a string value of an element is usually possible if the string functions suffice to break that value apart as needed, XSLT/XPath 2 and 3 are much more powerful for that than XSLT 1. Which version do you use?

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for your answer. The format of the Strawberry-Id is always the same and i got it with substring-before(@id, '/'). I use the XSLT Version 1 (I know there are better versions but that one was given to me). How do I use the `xsl:key` in that case?

Comment: If you have an `id="system://data/Strawberry/StrawberryID12345/?language=en-GB"` and use `substring-before(@id, '/')` you would get `system:` so I am not sure why that would help you to get that particular id.  Still not sure which part of the string you want but if you are restricted to XSLT 1 then you don't have more than the various `substring`/`substring-before`/`substring-after` you can combine to extract parts and make that part the `use` expression of the `xsl:key` and use a similar expression for the second argument of the `key` call.

Comment: No there was a misunderstanding by my side, generally in that case I used: `substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@id, 'data/'), '/'), '/')` to just get "StrawberryID12345". I thought you talked about the last segment. Somehow I need to get Link/StrawberryID = Fruits/Strawberry/StrawberryID. From there I just need the data from Fruits but thats the points where I don't have any clue how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a key, I am not sure how variable the elements names can be, below I have defined it for any grandchild element of the root element where both the parent and the child have an `id` attribute, and with XSLT 1 it is then an unreadable mess of nested `substring-before/substring-after` calls to extract stuff:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="fruit-ref" match="/*/*[@id]/*[@id]" use="substring-before(@id, '?')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Text/Link[@href]">
      <xsl:variable name="referenced-fruit" select="key('fruit-ref', @href)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="parent-fruit" select="$referenced-fruit/.."/>
      <a href="" my.id="{substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($parent-fruit/@id, '/'), '/'), '/'), '/'), '/')}"
                 my.majorVersion="{$parent-fruit/@majorVersion}"
                 my.type="{local-name($parent-fruit)}"
                 my.component="{substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($referenced-fruit/@id, '/'), '/'), '/'), '/'), '/')}_{$referenced-fruit/@version}_{local-name($referenced-fruit)}">Click me</a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqK gives the wanted result `<a href="" my.id="FruitsID12345" my.majorVersion="1" my.type="Fruits" my.component="StrawberryID12345_2_Strawberry">Click me</a>` so I hope that helps. I am not sure if the used key expression `use="substring-before(@id, '?')` is precise enough but of course that can also be made into a more specific (and less readable) nested string functions call mess.

Comment: Hey Martin, I have implemented your solution and it works. I did not come to the exact specification of the two variables. Thank you very much! Have a great day.